# A BufferedReader Example

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have multiple Files that I need to parse, so I created ReadMe.java (BufferedReader) that I need to call every time I need to process the file for pattern.  My question is, how can I pass the file path for each file and do the parse and print or save to an array. Do I do it in the controller or under ReadMe.java?   for the File path, I am getting it from the FXML controller using FileChooser (listed below):

```
public class ReadMe
{
    public String [] build()
    {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("fileName"))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

FXML Controller

```
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException
{
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("TXT files (*.txt)", "*.txt");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);
    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
    System.out.println(file);
    stage = (Stage) button.getScene().getWindow();
}
```

Comment: You could use  `String filename = file.getAbsolutePath();` to get the file's absolute path.

Comment: My file Path = file from File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage); but how can I pass this file value to ReadMe class and return the lines after parsing in an Array to use later or print to the console or display in an FXML file.

Comment: Rakesh, thank you for your input. While I am still waiting for an answer on my last comment. I went back to basics and tried to pass the value of the file path to a simpler BufferedReader class, and you are correct. with some error checking/validation I found out that I can't just path file variable and  I had no choice but to get its file.getAbsolutePath() to pass it over. Thank you so much for your input!! Greatly appreciated!!